# Get unique values for integration limits

Tags: numerical-integration, list-manipulation

For an multidimensional integration I want to build up the integration limits with the following code. (the length of vars is also variable)

```
x = 0.223144;
vars = {x1, x2, x3};
Table[{vars[[k]], -x/(1 + i), x/(1 + i)}, {k, 1, 3}, {i, 0, 2}]
```

which gives me:

```
{{{x1, -0.223144, 0.223144}, {x1, -0.111572, 0.111572}, {x1, -0.0743812, 0.0743812}}, {{x2, -0.223144,0.223144}, {x2, -0.111572, 0.111572}, {x2, -0.0743812,0.0743812}}, {{x3, -0.223144, 0.223144}, {x3, -0.111572,0.111572}, {x3, -0.0743812, 0.0743812}}}
```

As I see it, it makes an outer product. But I just want the the following integration variables with the corresponding limits.

```
{{x1, -0.223144, 0.223144}, {x2, -0.111572, 0.111572},{x3, -0.0743812, 0.0743812}}
```

How would I achieve that? Thank you

Comment: Thanks, but I also need to remove the unnecessary sublists of `x1,x2,x3`. I just want the first sublist for `x1`, second one for `x2`,...

Answer (score 2):

```
x = 0.223144;
vars = {x1, x2, x3};
Table[{vars[[k]], -x/k, x/k}, {k, 1, 3}]
(* {{x1, -0.223144, 0.223144}, {x2, -0.111572,  0.111572}, {x3, -0.0743813, 0.0743813}} *)
```